# Blazor .NET 8 SignInManager in controller doesn't set cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

the SignInManager in my controller doesn't set any cookie although sign in was successful:

Program.cs

```
  public static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
      var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

      // Add services to the container.
      builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
             .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
      builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
      builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
      builder.Services.AddControllers();
      builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
      builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
             .AddIdentityCookies();
      builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider,IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

      builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlite("DataSource=app.db"));
      builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyUser>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
          .AddSignInManager()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

      builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
      {
          opt.LoginPath = "/Login";
      });

      var app = builder.Build();

      // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
      if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
      {
          app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
          // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
          app.UseHsts();
      }
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseAntiforgery();
      app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
         .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
      app.MapControllers();
      await app.RunAsync();
  }
```

MyUser.cs:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser{}
```

AppDbContext.cs:

```
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    }
```

Login.razor.cs:

```
   private async Task OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
   {
            var request = new StringContent(
                                                 JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                                                 {
                                                     username    = model.Username,
                                                     password    = model.Password,
                                                     redirectUrl = navigationManager.GetRedirectUrl(),
                                                 }),
                                                 Encoding.UTF8,
                                                 MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
            var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(navigationManager.BaseUri);
            await httpClient.PostAsync("/User/SignIn", request).ConfigureAwait(false);
   }
```

Controller:

```
  public class LoginModel
  {
      public string Username    { get; set; }
      public string Password    { get; set; }
      public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
  }

  [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
  public class UserController : Controller
  {
      private readonly SignInManager<MyUser> signInManager;

      public UserController(SignInManager<MyUser> signInManager) => this.signInManager = signInManager;

      [HttpPost]
      public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromBody] LoginModel login)
      {
          var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Username, login.Password, false, false).ConfigureAwait(false);

          return Redirect(login.RedirectUrl);
      }
  }
```

The SignInResult is succeeded but I don't have any cookie after that if I inspect the browser's cookie storage.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't get the cookie is, you let the user login in is inside a MVC controller, but you use httpclient to post the request to that MVC controller SignIn method.

If you are using the httpClient.PostAsync, that means it will not do the redirect with the set-cookie header inside the response body when the login successfully inside the UserController's SignIn method.

To solve this issue, you need inside the `Login.razor.cs`'s await `httpClient.PostAsync("/User/SignIn", request).ConfigureAwait(false);` to get the response and get the set-cookie header and set the cookie by yourself do the redirect again.

This is not a good way, inside the official template for Blazor server app is directly using the identity inside the login razor component and it writes a redirectmamanger to set the cookie, instead of using the httpclient to call the user controller.

More details about how to create the identity login template ,you could refer to below image(select the individual accounts inside the authetnication type):

[image]

The generated login.razor like below:

```
@page "/Account/Login"

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using BlazorServerAppWebWithIdentity.Data

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject ILogger<Login> Logger
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IdentityRedirectManager RedirectManager

<PageTitle>Log in</PageTitle>

<h1>Log in</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <StatusMessage Message="@errorMessage" />
            <EditForm Model="Input" method="post" OnValidSubmit="LoginUser" FormName="login">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
                <hr />
                <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText @bind-Value="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Email" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="password" />
                    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Password" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label">
                        <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Input.RememberMe" class="darker-border-checkbox form-check-input" />
                        Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <a href="Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="@(NavigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters("Account/Register", new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["ReturnUrl"] = ReturnUrl }))">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="Account/ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </EditForm>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to log in.</h3>
            <hr />
            <ExternalLoginPicker />
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string? errorMessage;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    private string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        }
    }

    public async Task LoginUser()
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo(ReturnUrl);
        }
        else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo(
                "Account/LoginWith2fa",
                new() { ["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl, ["rememberMe"] = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            RedirectManager.RedirectTo("Account/Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Error: Invalid login attempt.";
        }
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; } = "";

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the redirect manager:

```
   internal sealed class IdentityRedirectManager(NavigationManager navigationManager)
   {
       public const string StatusCookieName = "Identity.StatusMessage";

       private static readonly CookieBuilder StatusCookieBuilder = new()
       {
           SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
           HttpOnly = true,
           IsEssential = true,
           MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
       };

       [DoesNotReturn]
       public void RedirectTo(string? uri)
       {
           uri ??= "";

           // Prevent open redirects.
           if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uri, UriKind.Relative))
           {
               uri = navigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(uri);
           }

           // During static rendering, NavigateTo throws a NavigationException which is handled by the framework as a redirect.
           // So as long as this is called from a statically rendered Identity component, the InvalidOperationException is never thrown.
           navigationManager.NavigateTo(uri);
           throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(IdentityRedirectManager)} can only be used during static rendering.");
       }

       [DoesNotReturn]
       public void RedirectTo(string uri, Dictionary<string, object?> queryParameters)
       {
           var uriWithoutQuery = navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(uri).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
           var newUri = navigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters(uriWithoutQuery, queryParameters);
           RedirectTo(newUri);
       }

       [DoesNotReturn]
       public void RedirectToWithStatus(string uri, string message, HttpContext context)
       {
           context.Response.Cookies.Append(StatusCookieName, message, StatusCookieBuilder.Build(context));
           RedirectTo(uri);
       }

       private string CurrentPath => navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navigationManager.Uri).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

       [DoesNotReturn]
       public void RedirectToCurrentPage() => RedirectTo(CurrentPath);

       [DoesNotReturn]
       public void RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus(string message, HttpContext context)
           => RedirectToWithStatus(CurrentPath, message, context);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My login page should be interactive. I get the error every time:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'

When I call

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(LoginModel.Username, LoginModel.Password, false, false)

inside my Login  private async Task OnValidSubmit()

Comment: What's your login page now?

Comment: Hey Brando Zhang my Login.razor is:

https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#yz2fwbruae9taggrfvc9f

Login.razor.cs:

https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#u9xnv29hxyr7hjbb7mklt5